# Based on the time counter how can I enable and disable button using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to enable a button when the time counter is Zero. Here I have two time counter 'First game starts in one time and another game starts in another time'. When the first button should be enable when the first time counter is zero, like that second one. Can anyone help me

My html code given below

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="timer2.js"></script>

    <div class='wrap' ng-app='app' ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <div class='time-to'>
        First Game Starts in...  <span countdown='10' date={{date1}} >&nbsp;</span><button ng-click="clickMe()" ng-show="showMe" >Play Now</button><br>
        Second Game Starts in... <span countdown='10' date={{date2}}>&nbsp;</span><button ng-click="clickMe()" ng-show="showMe" >Play Now</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Angularjs code  timer2.js   code given below

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.date1='16 November 2016 17:35:00';
    $scope.date2='17 November 2016 18:10:00';

});
    app.directive('countdown', [
        'Util',
        '$interval',
        function (Util, $interval) {
            return {
                restrict: 'AE',
                scope: { date: '@' },
                link: function (scope, element) {
                    var future;

                    future = new Date(scope.date);

                    element.showMe1 = true;
                    $interval(function () {
                        var diff;
                        diff = Math.floor((future.getTime() - new Date().getTime()) / 1000);
                        console.log(diff);
                        return element.text(Util.dhms(diff));
                    }, 1000);
                }
            };
        }
    ]).factory('Util', [function () {
            return {
                dhms: function (t) {
                    var days, hours, minutes, seconds;
                    days = Math.floor(t / 86400);
                    t -= days * 86400;
                    hours = Math.floor(t / 3600) % 24;
                    t -= hours * 3600;
                    minutes = Math.floor(t / 60) % 60;
                    t -= minutes * 60;
                    seconds = t % 60;
                    return [
                        days + 'd',
                        hours + 'h',
                        minutes + 'm',
                        seconds + 's'
                    ].join(' : ');
                }
            };
        }]);
```

I'm new in angularjs kindly please help me. If same solution exist in please give me the link. Thanks for all

Comment: how do you that your counter becomes zero?

Comment: I want to enable a button when the current time equal to mentioned time. Here I can get the difference value from "var diff"

Comment: are you starting a counter anywhere here?

Comment: No just I compare the current time and mentioned time is equal to same. If time equal i want to enable respective button

Comment: so the time is reached if diff becomes 0, right?

Comment: yes! you are right

Comment: check my answer, adding explanation, ask if any doubts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `two-way binding` to and fro from `directive` and  `controller` to achieve this.

Take a scope variables in your controller named `disabled1` and `disabled2` and make a two-way binding from the directive to te controller.

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.disabled1 = true;
    $scope.disabled2 = true;
    $scope.date1='16 November 2016 17:35:00';
    $scope.date2='17 November 2016 18:10:00';

});
```

**Directive:**

```
app.directive('countdown', [
        'Util',
        '$interval',
        function (Util, $interval) {
            return {
                restrict: 'AE',
                scope: { 
                    date: '@',
                    disabled: '='
                 },
                link: function (scope, element) {
                    var future;

                    future = new Date(scope.date);

                    element.showMe1 = true;
                    $interval(function () {
                        var diff;
                        diff = Math.floor((future.getTime() - new Date().getTime()) / 1000);
                        console.log(diff);
                        if(diff == 0)
                        {
                            scope.disabled = false;
                        }
                        return element.text(Util.dhms(diff));
                    }, 1000);
                }
            };
        }
    ])
```

Check the scope,

```
scope: { 
         date: '@',
         disabled: '='
      }
```

**View:**

```
<div class='wrap' ng-app='app' ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div class='time-to'>
    First Game Starts in...  <span countdown='10' date={{date1}} disabled="disabled1">&nbsp;</span><button ng-click="clickMe()" ng-show="showMe" ng-disabled="disabled1">Play Now</button><br>
    Second Game Starts in... <span countdown='10' date={{date2}} disabled="disabled2" >&nbsp;</span><button ng-click="clickMe()" ng-show="showMe" ng-disabled="disabled2">Play Now</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the view I am sending the **disabled value through the attribute directive and using it in the directive**.

**If that value changes in the directive, it is reflected back to the view.**

Using that technique, I used `ng-disabled = "disabled1"` and `ng-disabled = "disabled2"` for respective buttons.

[a reference for 2-way binding](http://www.journaldev.com/7572/angularjs-isolate-scope-two-way-binding-example)

Comment: @Rijo, checked my answer?

Comment: Is it possible to assign the date value to the text field?

Comment: use a date picker on the text field, and convert to your format from your controller.

Comment: @sarvan how can redirect when  if(diff< 0)

Comment: I added this code but its not working  if(diff<0) {
                            $window.location.href = '/home.html';
                        }